Как правильно в данном случае употребить слово "самой" или "самого" преподавателя?
С советами по решению задач от самой преподавателя 2 курса – Марии Николаевны можно ознакомиться по ссылке.

Либо самой преподавательницы...,либо от самого преподавателя... М.Н.
Зависит от контекста. В официальном стиле предпочтительным является второй вариант.
